# Create a field to save the 'FullPhotoURL' of a user

Tags: user, standard-objects, standard-field

anyone know how to Create a field to save the 'FullPhotoURL' of a user?

or display a user profile pic on a custom object

Answer (score 0):

Create a field on the custom object of type URL, e.g. `MyObject__c.UserPhotoUrl__c`

Retrieve the FullPhotoURL of the user (in this example, the current user):

```
User currentUser = [SELECT FullPhotoUrl FROM user WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
```

Save a custom object record with the user's FullPhotoUrl:

```
MyObject__c myObject = new MyObject__c();
myObject.UserPhotoUrl__c = currentUser.FullPhotoUrl;
insert myObject;
```